# Using a variable in enquire.js register method

Tags: javascript, jquery, enquire.js

I am trying to using a variable in the register method of enquire.js. I'm going to be reusing enquire in a few different places in my javascript file, so I would like to be able to manage the widths it is using easier.

This is the basic call

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:860px)", {

});
```

This is sort of what I was hoping I could do but it's not working.

```
var $small = '600px';

enquire.register("screen and (max-width:'$small')", {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. Me being stupid and forgetting how concatenating works. I needed to end the string with the same type of quotes and then use the plus symbol to concatenate the variable. I then used the same quotes again to finish open and close the remainder of the string.

```
var $small = '600px';

enquire.register("screen and (max-width:" + $small + ")", {

});
```